# looping and prepending javascript to html

Tags: javascript, html

I am going to have to repost my previous question because I need to reformulate what I need.

So, here it goes.

I have a webpage containing some list items,

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<p>Items are ordered Alphabetically and I want the text to be untouched</p>
</div>
```

All of these list items are contained in a folder on my computer. What I want to do is not have to manually input the ../Html/1.html , ../Html/2.html, ... instead, I was hoping to find a script to do the job for me.

All the items are numbered in numerical order, starting at 1 all the way to 100.
So I know iterating using i++ might come in handy in a loop. But I really dont know more than that!

Comment: do you have jquery or just pure javascript?
can you add an id to the container?

Comment: @Spark id rather have it pure js, the thing about the class is i have it on several places, so id rather stick to it.

Comment: You're not going to be able to get javascript (running in a secure state on somebody's computer) being able to do any searching of a directory on your server. You'll need a server-side language to achieve this

Comment: @Dino: What *freefaller* meant is that, that page of yours, must be opened as a local HTML file and its URL would be like `file://D/MyFiles/MyPage.html` if you want the page to be able to access your local computer files. As for the question, it depends. What do you want to do with the file path (show as text, links, iframe?). Where exactly you want to put them?

Comment: @Jay if he knows the names of the files are just numbers and needs links only he can loop and use i+'.html' to get the filename

I don't think the op wants to read the files nor the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
<div id="theContainer" class="container">
  <p>Items are ordered Alphabetically and I want the text to be untouched</p>
</div>

<script>
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var container = document.getElementById('theContainer'), i, p, s;
  var numStart = 1, numEnd = 100;
  var path = '../Html/*.html'; //use "*" to substitute the number
  for (i = numStart; i <= numEnd; i++) {
    p = path.replace(/\*/,i);
    s += '<li><a href="' + encodeURI(p) + '">' + p + '</a></li>';
  }
  container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + '<ol>' + s + '</ol>';
}, false);
</script>
```